# Difference in new Date() output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I tried with two methods to generate Date first by passing whole date string and second with year, month, day combination. But I am getting different outputs while the same date is being provided. The Day is not right. It should be 30 June in the first too.

```js
const oldDate = new Date('2020-06-30');
const newDate = new Date('2020', '05', '30');

console.log(oldDate.toString(), newDate.toString());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: What are you expecting? Are the outputs meant to be different?

Comment: Consider reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date as it explains why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate a `Date` by passing a string, it's supposed to be a full [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string which specifies the time zone. As you dont specify it, it takes GMT+0, and you seem to be located at GMT-7. You should write this instead:

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-06-30T00:00:00-07:00').toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` constructor that accepts multiple arguments expects them to be **numbers**, and accepts the month number as a 0-based value (0 = January). The values are expected to be in **local** time.

The `Date` constructor accepting a single string argument *parses* the string according to [the specified rules](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) (which apply to your example) and, possibly, unspecified fallback rules the JavaScript engine implementer chose to add (in your case, though, the fallback isn't necessary). When there's no timezone indicator on the string, Date-only forms such as yours are parsed in UTC (date/time forms are parsed in local time).

(The `Date` constructor accepting a single *number* expects that number to be milliseconds-since-The-Epoch [Jan 1st, 1970 at midnight, UTC].)

Answer (score 0):

Below format is considered as GMT time and it tries to convert to your local timezone. That's why you notice 7 hours subtracted.

> new Date('2020-06-30')

whereas,

Below format is considered as local timezone and no further conversion happen.

> new Date('2020', '05', '30');

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date):

> - dateString
>   A string value representing a date, specified in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method. (These formats are IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps, and also strings in a version of ISO8601.)
>
> Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.
> Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only.
> Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Therefore, when you create date via `new Date("2020-06-30")` it creates date object in 0 timezone and adjusts time to show it equal to your time zone.